# TextInput loses focus if keyboard overlaps it on Android

Tags: react-native, android-softkeyboard, react-native-textinput

I have a very simple `TextInput` component on a screen like and an `onEndEditing` method like so:

```
<TextInput
    style={Styles.input}
    placeholder='testing placeholder'
    placeholderTextColor={Colors.gray}
    onEndEditing={this.onEndEditing}
    selectionColor={Colors.darkCursor}>
</TextInput>

onEndEditing = async (event): Promise<void> => {
    console.log('in update');
};
```

It is inside of a `FlatList` which is wrapped in a `KeyboardAvoidingView`.

On Android, when the `TextInput` is tapped on and focused, if the onscreen keyboard pops up and overlaps the input, the input will lose focus and must be tapped on again. However, if the keyboard DOES NOT overlap the input, the input will keep its original focus. This does not happen on iOS.

I'm noticing that the `onEndEditing` method is called when the input loses focus from the keyboard overlap.

Update: Wrapping the `FlatList` in a `ScrollView` fixes it for whatever reason, but obviously that is not a good solution.